# How to easily link a document with others

Tags: documentation, wiki, organization

let's say that in order for me to make clear how my program works or even for the own sake of documentation I am writing some text document in word or whatever text editor or online wit google docs, etc. Let's say that at some part of the document I open a new one and extend there the idea. Then later, I go back to the "master" document and add some hyperlink or just put reference (it follows in doc XXXX, page YYYY). I wonder what could be the fastest approach to do this

```
* google docs adding easily hyperlink? but how can I organize docs effectively?
* some text editor with this functionality?
```

Thanks for your responses

P.D. Are there easier solutions than WIKI's? In terms of easiness of installation and setup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiki's are definitely great for that. I have used two notetaking solutions that have what you want (I've used more, but these were the best for me).

- TiddlyWiki

  - Great feature set since it's javascript/html with wiki functionality: intralinking to pages you create, embedding of images from any directory, hyperlinks, and printability
  - Also has an amazing amount of plugins at places like TiddlyTools and other repos like it
  - I combined it with TeamTasks which not only made it look better, but brought in some todo functionality; with TiddlyWiki Address Book (twab) for contact management, and several other plugins that worked great
- emacs + orgmode

  - This is my top choice today for notetaking and all kinds of stuff
  - It is literally unbelievable. Todos, contacts, scheduling, linking, export to html, export to PDF via LaTeX, interfacing with gnuplot, TikZ, ditaa, R (like Matlab), etc.
  - Inter and intralinking are very easy. See [THIS](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/org/Handling-links.html) for specifically how orgmode deals with various linking.

Lastly, if orgmode sounds interesting, I would strongly recommend checking out the orgmode wiki, Worg, where tutorials, videos, and screencasts exist.

Your initial inquiry mentions simplicity, so perhaps one of the wikis is best. If you're unfamiliar with them, it's quite easy to just download a copy (just an html file), open it in a browser and play around. There's a lot of documentation out there to help you and your linking is as often as easy as writing something like [[page::section]] or similar in your document.

On the other hand, if you're looking for advanced usage and especially exporting of documents, I have yet to find anything to beat orgmode for me! I highly recommend it and the mailing list is very, very active and supportive.

Answer (score 0):

Every document type or system has its own standard for interlinking documents.  HTML has hyperlinks, MS Word has document references, etc.  I personally find wikis to be the easiest way to grow and expand interlinked documents.  HTML hyperlinks are probably the most common standard way of linking documents, and wiki syntax makes it especially easy.